# Error: install sonata ecommerce

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php, sonata-admin, knpmenubundle

I'm trying to install sonata ecommerce , but when i run composer update, i have this Error:

```
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Can only install one of: knplabs/knp-menu-bundle[2.1.x-dev, 1.1.x-dev].
    - Can only install one of: knplabs/knp-menu-bundle[v2.0.0, 1.1.x-dev].
    - Can only install one of: knplabs/knp-menu-bundle[v2.0.0-alpha1, 1.1.x-dev]
.
    - Can only install one of: knplabs/knp-menu-bundle[v2.0.0-alpha2, 1.1.x-dev]
.
    - Can only install one of: knplabs/knp-menu-bundle[v2.1.0, 1.1.x-dev].
    - Can only install one of: knplabs/knp-menu-bundle[1.1.x-dev, v2.1.0].
    - sonata-project/ecommerce dev-master requires knplabs/knp-menu-bundle ~1.1
-> satisfiable by knplabs/knp-menu-bundle[1.1.x-dev].
    - Installation request for sonata-project/ecommerce dev-master -> satisfiabl
e by sonata-project/ecommerce[dev-master].
    - Installation request for knplabs/knp-menu-bundle ~2.0 -> satisfiable by kn
plabs/knp-menu-bundle[2.1.x-dev, v2.0.0, v2.0.0-alpha1, v2.0.0-alpha2, v2.1.0].
```

**This is my composer json**

```
{
    "name": "symfony/framework-standard-edition",
    "license": "MIT",
    "type": "project",
    "description": "The \"Symfony Standard Edition\" distribution",
    "autoload": {
        "psr-0": { "": "src/", "SymfonyStandard": "app/" }

    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "prefer-stable": true,
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.3.9",
        "symfony/symfony": "2.7.*",
        "doctrine/orm": "~2.2,>=2.2.3,<2.5",
        "doctrine/dbal": "<2.5",
        "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "~1.4",
        "twig/extensions": "~1.0",
        "symfony/assetic-bundle": "2.6.0",
        "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "~2.3",
        "symfony/monolog-bundle": "~2.4",
        "sensio/distribution-bundle": "~3.0,>=3.0.12",
        "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "~3.0,>=3.0.2",
        "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler": "~2.0",
        "leafo/lessphp": "*",
        "twitter/bootstrap": "*",
        "mremi/contact-bundle": "dev-master",
        "symfony/twig-bridge": "2.3.*",
        "genemu/form-bundle": "2.2.*",
        "components/jquery":"dev-master",
        "friendsofsymfony/user-bundle": "~1.3",
        "hwi/oauth-bundle": "0.4.*@dev",
        "knplabs/gaufrette": "~0.1.6",
        "knplabs/knp-menu-bundle": "~2.0",
        "sonata-project/user-bundle": "2.3.*@dev",
        "sonata-project/block-bundle": "~2.3@dev",
        "sonata-project/admin-bundle": "~2.4@dev",
        "sonata-project/page-bundle": "~2.3",
        "sonata-project/datagrid-bundle": "2.2.*@dev",
        "symfony-cmf/routing-bundle": "~1.1",
        "sonata-project/core-bundle": "~2.2@dev",
        "sonata-project/doctrine-orm-admin-bundle": "~2.2",
        "sonata-project/easy-extends-bundle": "~2.1",
        "sonata-project/comment-bundle": "~2.2@dev",
        "sonata-project/ecommerce": "dev-master"

    },
    "require-dev": {
        "sensio/generator-bundle": "~2.3"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "SymfonyStandard\\Composer::hookRootPackageInstall"
        ],
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "Incenteev\\ParameterHandler\\ScriptHandler::buildParameters",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::removeSymfonyStandardFiles"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "Incenteev\\ParameterHandler\\ScriptHandler::buildParameters",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::removeSymfonyStandardFiles"
        ]
    },
    "config": {
        "bin-dir": "bin"
    },
    "extra": {
        "symfony-app-dir": "app",
        "symfony-web-dir": "web",
        "symfony-assets-install": "relative",
        "symfony-assets-install":"symlink",
        "incenteev-parameters": {
            "file": "app/config/parameters.yml"
        },
        "branch-alias": {
            "dev-master": "2.7-dev"
        }
    }
}
```

i tried to replaced "knplabs/knp-menu-bundle": "~2.0",   by   knplabs/knp-menu-bundle": "2.0.@dev", but i'm still having an error.

Someone have any idea how to solved my problem. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Important lines from the error message:

- Installation request for sonata-project/ecommerce dev-master
- sonata-project/ecommerce dev-master requires **knplabs/knp-menu-bundle ~1.1**
- Installation request for **knplabs/knp-menu-bundle ~2.0**

So you require `knplabs/knp-menu-bundle` `~2.0`, while sonata ecommerce requires version `~1.1`. There is no version that matches both `>=1.1,<2.0` and `>=2.0,<3.0`, resulting in a resolving conflict.

So either find a KnpMenuBundle 2 supporting version of Sonata ecommerce or downgrade to KnpMenuBundle 1 in your application.

Comment: Hi Wouter J, thank you for your answer. i understand what you said.....is a bit complicated because the version of sonata user bundle and admin bundle that i'm using required knplabs/knp-menu-bundle ~2.0. and it seems that there is not yet a version 2 of KnpMenuBundle supporting Sonata ecommerce dev-master. So to solved my error  i had to change this line "sonata-project/ecommerce": "dev-master"  by this one "sonata-project/ecommerce": "dev-develop". And now everything is working fine.